# How to show Bigcommerce product categories in wordpress sidebar

Tags: wordpress, bigcommerce

I need to show a list of categories from bigcommerce to WordPress sidebar just like this website

https://www.kaiserwillys.com/

There is no shortcode to show categories list using bigcommerce wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this shortcode
Ref.->  [BigCommerce for WordPress Products](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/BigCommerce-for-WordPress-Products)

```
[bigcommerce_product category="category_name"]
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, But this shortcode gives the products from a particular category, I need the list of categories and subcategories just the reference website I have mentioned.